# How to sort an all-digit matrix in perl

Tags: perl, sorting, matrix, sql-order-by

Assume there is an m by n all-digit matrix:

```
X11 X12 ... X1n<br>
X21 X22 ... X2n<br>
...<br>
Xmn Xmn ... Xmn
```

I need help to write a method that somewhat like 'order by' in ansi sql. This method shall be able to sort the matrix by ANY number of column indices passed in at cmdline.

For example, if cmdline is:

```
% myOrderby -col 1,2,5
```

It'll sort the matrix by columns 1, 2 and 5.

However, if cmdline is

```
% myOrderby -col 1,4,8,11
```

then it would sort the matrix by columns 1, 4, 8 and 11.

I know how to implement the method if there was a fixed maximum number of columns to "order by". I am looking for a method that can sort a matrix based on any number of columns.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can sort by an arbitrary number of fields

```
# note, your columns start at 1, while arrays index from 0
my @cols = map($_-1, @param_cols);
my @sorted = sort {
    my $r = 0;
    $r ||= $a->[$_] <=> $b->[$_] for @cols;
    return $r;
} @matrix;
```

Answer (score 2):

You will loop through the indices, breaking out of the loop when the comparison shows a difference.

```
@M = map{$a=$_;map{$b=$_;map{$c=$_;map{$d=$_;
         map[$a,$b,$c,$d,$_],2,1}1,2}2,1}1,2}2,1;

sub by_cols {
    my ($row1,$row2,@indices) = @_;
    foreach my $col (@indices) {
        my $d = $row1->[$col] <=> $row2->[$col];
        return $d if $d;
    }
    return 0;
}

print "@$_\n" for sort { by_cols($a,$b, 3,4,1) } @M;
```

### Output

```
2 1 2 1 1
2 1 1 1 1
1 1 2 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 1 1
2 2 1 1 1
1 2 2 1 1
1 2 1 1 1
2 1 2 1 2
2 1 1 1 2
1 1 2 1 2
1 1 1 1 2
2 2 2 1 2
2 2 1 1 2
1 2 2 1 2
1 2 1 1 2
2 1 2 2 1
2 1 1 2 1
1 1 2 2 1
1 1 1 2 1
2 2 2 2 1
2 2 1 2 1
1 2 2 2 1
1 2 1 2 1
2 1 2 2 2
2 1 1 2 2
1 1 2 2 2
1 1 1 2 2
2 2 2 2 2
2 2 1 2 2
1 2 2 2 2
1 2 1 2 2
```